# SwitchMap vs MergeMap in the #ngrx example

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

Below is code from the Ngrx example: https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/effects/book.ts My question is why in the first @Effect,  it uses `switchMap` while the others use `mergeMap`. Is that because the first @Effect is dealing with network, and with the `switchMap` you can cancel the previous network request if it's running?

```js
@Effect() search$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(BookActions.SEARCH)
    .map<string>(toPayload)
    .filter(query => query !== '')
    .switchMap(query => this.googleBooks.searchBooks(query)
      .map(books => this.bookActions.searchComplete(books))
      .catch(() => Observable.of(this.bookActions.searchComplete([])))
    );


  @Effect() clearSearch$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(BookActions.SEARCH)
    .map<string>(toPayload)
    .filter(query => query === '')
    .mapTo(this.bookActions.searchComplete([]));


  @Effect() addBookToCollection$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(BookActions.ADD_TO_COLLECTION)
    .map<Book>(toPayload)
    .mergeMap(book => this.db.insert('books', [ book ])
      .mapTo(this.bookActions.addToCollectionSuccess(book))
      .catch(() => Observable.of(
        this.bookActions.addToCollectionFail(book)
      ))
    );


  @Effect() removeBookFromCollection$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(BookActions.REMOVE_FROM_COLLECTION)
    .map<Book>(toPayload)
    .mergeMap(book => this.db.executeWrite('books', 'delete', [ book.id ])
      .mapTo(this.bookActions.removeFromCollectionSuccess(book))
      .catch(() => Observable.of(
        this.bookActions.removeFromCollectionFail(book)
      ))
    );
}
```

Comment: I came here looking for what the difference is, the clearest explanation I've come across is: `When you hear the word merge, think — use every­thing on all the streams aka. merge every­thing. Whereas when you hear the word switch, think — switch to using data on the newer stream` http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/03/29/switchmap-vs-flatmap-rxjs/

Answer (score 104):

You are correct; `switchMap` will unsubscribe from the `Observable` returned by its `project` argument as soon as it has invoked the `project` function again to produce a new `Observable`.

RxJs is incredibly powerful and dense, but its high level of abstraction can sometimes make code hard to understand. Let me debunk the marble diagrams and docs given by @Andy Hole a little and bring them up to date. You may find the [marble syntax reference](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md) highly valuable to better understand rxjs operators from their tests (at least I found this missing/not highlighted enough in the [official docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/)).

### mergeMap

[image: mergeMap]

The first line in the diagram is the source Observable which emits `(1,3,5)` at different times. The second line in the diagram is the prototypical Observable returned by the `project` function `i => ...` passed to the `.mergeMap()` operator.

When the source Observable emits the item `1`, `mergeMap()` invokes the `project` function with `i=1`. The returned Observable will emit `10` three times, every 10 frames (see [marble syntax reference](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md)). The same happens when the source Observable emits item `3` and the `project` function creates an Observable that emits `30` three times. Note that the result of `mergeMap()` contains all three elements generated by each Observable returned from `project`.

### switchMap

[image: switchMap]
This is different with `switchMap()`, which will unsubscribe from the Observable returned by `project` as soon as it has invoked it again on a new element. The marble diagram indicates this with the missing third `30` item in the output Observable.

In the example you have given, this leads to the cancellation of the pending search request. This is a **very nice but hard-to-get-right** property, which you get for free by combining `switchMap()` with cancellable Observables returned by Angular's `Http` service. This can save you a lot of headaches without worrying about properly handling all the race conditions that typically occur with async cancellation.

Answer (score 9):

You are right.

As you can see, switchMap is used with search functionality. The searchbox in this example is programmed to basically emit a search request when the user enters text in the textbox (with a 350ms debounce or delay).

This means that when the user enters 'har', ngrx sends a search request to the service. When the user enters another letter 'r', the previous request is canceled (since we are not interested in 'har' anymore, but 'harr').

It is very nicely shown in the marble diagrams provided in another answer.
In mergeMap, the previous Observables are not canceled and therefore '30' and '50' are mixed together. Using switchMap, only the 5s are emitted, because the 3's are canceled.

Answer (score 3):

### mergeMap

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable.
>
> Maps each value to an Observable, then flattens all of these inner Observables using mergeAll.

[image]

### switchMap

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, emitting values only from the most recently projected Observable.
>
> Maps each value to an Observable, then flattens all of these inner Observables using switch.

[image]

Source: [ES6 Observables in RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html)

Comment: I am not looking for the definition of the mergeMap and switchMap

Answer (score 0):

You don't want an API save data request to cancel. That is why you would use mergeMap. A search query can be thrown away, no loss of data, and the user might be editing their query and are not interested in the data for the old one. Hence switchMap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are no longer concerned with the response of the previous request when a new Input arrives switchMap is a suitable operator than mergeMap.